# Get HTML data from table row click into javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My end goal is to click a row on the table and for that to populate in the form next to it for an update. This code here is simply just "attempting" to click a row and for it to display in a Javascript alert with the row data, before I code the population of the form.

Here I have populated the table using PHP. The TR class have "updatetbl" which is later used with the javascript. I used the code example from this question: [Get the table row data with a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356497/get-the-table-row-data-with-a-click)

```
if ($patients->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $patients-> fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<tr class="updatetbl">';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['Forename'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['Surname'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['DOB'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['Address'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['Postcode'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['Telephone'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td class="updatetbl">' . $row['Email'] . '</td>';
         echo '<tr>';
     }
}else{
  echo "0 results";
}
```

I am trying to get the data, firstly, into an alert with Javascript (I just want to see that I have the data before putting into the form)

To populate the alert, and register the click I have the following javascript.

```
<script>
$("tr.updatetbl").click(function(){
   var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function(){
       return $(this).text();
   }).get();

    alert("Data = "+ $trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $trim(tableData[1]) + " , "
        + $trim(tableData[2]) + " , " + $trim(tableData[3]) + " , "));
});
</script>
```

To my knowledge the tr.updatetbl concentrates on a click here? And then gathers the table data..

Any ideas?

**Update: I do have  etc.**

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Forename</th>
             <th>Surname</th>
             <th>D.O.B</th>
             <th>Address</th>
             <th>Postcode</th>
             <th>Tel</th>
             <th>Email</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>

     <?php
        $servername = removed
        $dbname = removed
        $username = removed
        $password = removed

        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($connection->connect_error) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . $connection->connect_error);
       }

     $sql = "SELECT ID, Forename, Surname, DOB, Telephone, Email, Address, Postcode FROM people";
      $people= $connection->query($sql);

      if ($patients->num_rows > 0){
           while($row = $patients-> fetch_assoc()) {
              echo '<tr class="updatetbl">';
              echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['Forename'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['Surname'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['DOB'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['Address'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['Postcode'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['Telephone'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $row['Email'] . '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
        }

 }
  else
 {
  echo "0 results";
 }
  $connection->close();
  ?>
 </table>
```

**Solved:**

I have it figured out - I put the compiled code into a new jFiddle with the javascript and it still didn't work. I couldn't figure why, so I looked at yours and I noticed at the side you had the library as jQuery! Mine was standard JS. So I realised that I hadn't included the `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

I voted the below answer because I was helped effortlessly although I am sure after all of this other answers will work.

Comment: One problem you'll have here is that you're not closing the <tr> correctly.

Comment: Just updated that, silly me! Although unfortunately still doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: You cannot listen for a "click" event on a table row. It simply is not raised. Instead you have to listen to click events of the _content_ of the rows cells.

Comment: Remove the `updatetbl`  class from tds, you dont need them. (@arkascha : event works on TR)

Comment: No problem listening for a click on TR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one ")" at the end this line which is not needed, thats why it doesnt work :

```
`alert("Data = "+ $trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $trim(tableData[1]) + " , "
    + $trim(tableData[2]) + " , " + $trim(tableData[3]) + " , ")); which isnt needed.
```

Moreover, just add the class `updatetbl` on row.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="updatetbl">
        <td >ID</td>
        <td >Forename</td>
        <td >Surname</td>
        <td >DOB</td>
        <td >Address</td>
        <td >Postcode</td>
        <td >Telephone</td>
        <td >Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

JS :

```
$(".updatetbl").click(function(){
   var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function(){
       return $(this).text();
   }).get();

    alert("Data = "+ tableData[0] + " , " + tableData[1] + " , "
        + tableData[2] + " , " + tableData[3] + " , ");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated those silly errors - although still doesn't seem to register the click.

Comment: Do you have other JS on your page ? Do you have a debugger like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) for example ? It helps to check javascript errors

Comment: I have firebug, but it doesn't raise any issues regarding errors within the console.

Comment: Ok my bad, its just that you forget to declare `<table>` and `<tbody>` so the `<tr>` is not seen by javascript.

Comment: I do have <table> etc, it is just outside the code (I have updated the main post with this code) it's just that there was a lot of php there.

Comment: Ok, so I would suggest you to do a kind of reverse engineering. I mean, start from the basic code I give you and then implement back step by step your own code. There should be some of your code which prevent javascript from working. It can be a misclosed tag, or other JS.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: I didnt checked your update. Did you try by adding the `tbody` ?

Comment: I have it figured out - I put the compiled code into a new jFiddle with the javascript and it still didn't work. I couldn't figure why, so I looked at yours and I noticed at the side you had the library as jQuery! Mine was standard JS. So I realised that I hadn't included the `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`  So I added that to my project and it worked! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code for this

```
$( "table tr.updatetbl" ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = [];
    $( this ).find( "td" ).each( function(){ data.push( $.trim( $( this ).text() ) ) } );
    console.log( data );
});
```

fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/4tk4w0ua/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
        $("tr.updatetbl").click(function(){

            var data = [];

            $("tr.updatetbl td").each(function(i, td){
                data.push(td.text());
            });

            console.log(data);

        });
```