# How to return table row data on click of row td?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, html-table

I'm trying to return the row data as an array when I click a button on that table row. Searching on SO gave me [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356497/get-the-table-row-data-with-a-click) using `children.map`.

But when I run the web app and click a the success button on any of the table rows, the array returned in the console is empty.

[image]

I've verified that each table row contains data so I'm not sure why no data is returned using the map function.

I also know that the function is firing on click of the buttons with `class="btn-success".`

Question:

How to return table row data on click of row td?

This is the gist of the table and the associated jQuery function to map the row data:

```
<table id="statusTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered results">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="visibility:hidden;" >ID</th>
                    <th>IT Owner</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Update Record</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Model.ReleaseStatus)
            {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="visibility:hidden;" >@Html.Raw(row.ID)</td>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(row.Configuration)</td>
                        <td id="app_name" class="links" style="font-size: 14px;">@row.ID</td>
                        <td>@row.Configuration_Item</td>
                        <td>@row.Configuration_Name</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button></td>
                    </tr>
              }
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

JQuery function:

```
$(".btn-success").click(function () {
            var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            console.log(tableData);
        });
```

Comment: Your button has no `td` children... You probably want: `var btn = this; $(this).closest('tr').children().not(function(){return !$(this).find(btn).length;}).map(...)`

Comment: You want text of which column?

Comment: `$(this).children("td").map(function () {` change to `$(this).closest('tr').find("td").map(function () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find `tr`, then `td`s

**Updated**

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col #1</td>     
        <td>col #2</td>
        <td>            
            <button type="button">click me</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children("td"),
        len = $td.length;       

    var tableData = $td.map(function(i) {   
        if(i < len -1)
            return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    console.log(tableData); // ["col #1", "col #2"]
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/r19bhopb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is the button that has no children
Change in $("#statusTable") that is the table

```
 $(".btn-success").click(function () {
        var tableData = $('#statusTable').children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        console.log(tableData);
    });
```

Comment: This would not be a good idea.  Look at what rows you're selecting vs the rows that should be selected (ie all vs the one being clicked).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try each loop of td :

```
$(".btn-success").click(function () {
    var selector = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    var items = [];
    $(this.parentElement.parentElement.children).each(function(a,b){            
        items.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(items);
});
```

Comment: If you're using jquery, use jquery - don't mix+match with javascript node travseral.    In this cases `.closest("tr")` is the best match as `.parent().parent()` makes the html too brittle.