# Reading values from table on tr click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I started learning jquery few days ago and now i'm  facing one problem in retrieving values from table using jquery

```
<table id="tblsample">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">Data one</td>
    <td id="2">Data two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3">Data one</td>
    <td id="4">Data two</td>
  </tr> 
<tr>
    <td id="4">Data one</td>
    <td id="5">Data two</td>
  </tr>
  .
  .
  .

</table>
```

if i click on the first tr row i want to read  "2"

```
 <td id="2">Data two</td>
```

This is for binding a dropdown based on value.

for first td's i did something like below only for reading the text part

```
 $('#tblsample tr td').click(function () {

    var cval = $(this).text();
    $(txtCountry).val(cval);//Binding to textbox - "Data One"

});
```

How can i take the id's of second td's for each tr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the table row data with a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356497/get-the-table-row-data-with-a-click)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `$(this).parent()` to trigger your tr, and use `find` :

```
let nextTdId = parseInt($(this).attr('id')) + 1; //get the next td id
$(this).parent().find(nextTdId); //get the next td
```

Or you can just select the 2nd child of the parent of your td, or use `$(this).siblings()[0]`, many solutions indeed

Answer (score 0):

With QJuery ,

```
$("tr.myTable").click(function() {
var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(tableData);
});
```