# Read each table row in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this table which contains essential information about my book cart

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>School No</th>
    <th>Resource Type</th> 
    <th>Resource No.</th>
    <th>Resource Title</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>201912621</td>
    <td>Book</td> 
    <td>099918723</td>
    <td>Sample Title</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To make it short how can I read each row in my table and ouput it like this in jquery.

```
var row1= $("#SchoolNo").val();
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add the HTML...

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356497/get-the-table-row-data-with-a-click

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated the question sorry i forgot :)

Comment: Ok, now there's just the confusion over what you want to read out :) There's no `#SchoolNo` element, and no form elements to read a `val()` from...? What output are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to get the value of each row from my table

Comment: that #SchoolNo is an example only of what output i want to achieve in jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
function table2array(){
  var out=[];
  $('table tr').each(function(){
    var el=[]
    $(this).children('td').each(function(){
     el.push($(this).text());
    });
     if(el.length){
      out.push(el);
     }
  });
  return out;
}

$('#btn_get_all').click(function(){
 var my_arr=table2array();
 console.log(my_arr);
});

$('#btn_get_one').click(function(){
 var my_arr=table2array();
 alert(my_arr[1][3]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>






<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>School No</th>
    <th>Resource Type</th>
    <th>Resource No.</th>
    <th>Resource Title</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>201912621</td>
    <td>Book</td>
    <td>099918723</td>
    <td>Sample Title</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>201912456</td>
    <td>Cd</td>
    <td>099918745</td>
    <td>Sample Title 2</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<input type="button" id="btn_get_all" value="get all TABLE content"></br>
<input type="button" id="btn_get_one" value="get SELL(1,3)">
```